# Easy code I copied straight off a tutorial not working, Javascript Notepad++

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>

</h1>
<script>

//alert("Hello World");
//console.log("Hi world");
let drawTo = document.querySelector('h1');
drawTo.textContext = "Hello World";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, I am not too sure how to fix it and I don't think theres anything wrong with the CODE itself, and when i passed it through an online IDE i got this error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled.

Opened it in Brave browser to find there was no text, just blank

Comment: so, you've created this file in notepad++ ... great ... what did you do with this file? did you open it in a *web browser*?

Comment: Did you set the file extension to be `.html`?

Comment: NP++ is irrelevant. The browser doesn't care how the text got into the file it runs. Your "online IDE" (it's good to say which one, specifically) is probably running NodeJS. This is HTML code here, with JS embedded in a script tag, so you need to run it in a browser.

Comment: *"when i passed it through an online IDE"* - Can you elaborate on what specifically you mean by that?

Comment: This is an html file, not a javascript file. Your online ide thought you were giving it jsx which is a html-like markup syntax for javascript. Also it's `textContent` not `textContext`

Comment: @lejlun yes, is that why?

Comment: @mintymoes If you used the `.html` extension you have nothing to worry about. The syntax error mentioned in the post below is likely what's causing your error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no JavaScript property called `textContext`. If you want to add text inside your `h1` element using JavaScript, you can either use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property or the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property like this:

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1></h1>

<script>
let drawTo = document.querySelector('h1');
drawTo.textContent = "Hello World";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```